# Any idea why wrapping a WP shortcode in a div hides all page content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Didn't see anyone else having this issue in similar questions. Basically I have a plugin shortcode which I wrap in a simple div to try to work on styling (it shows simple text so I want it to look nicer around the edges).

I enter:

`<div style="border: 1px solid; border-color:#999;">
[stdailytip group="Tip" date="show" title="show"]
</div>`

Then everything on the page is hidden except for the table with images at the top and the wordpress (Edit) function inside my 1px box. I'm completely confused by this as I don't have any other messed up divs on the page. All text simply vanishes. I'm using the daily tip plugin. I assume the problem might be plugin specific.

Comment: Does the shortcode work correctly when it's not used inside a wrapper div? Can you post what the shortcode is outputting in the page source?

Comment: Can you show code for your shortcode?

Comment: Also why is the div code not part of what the short tag returns?